# How to combine two usages of # into one and speed up the code?

Tags: programming, functions, performance-tuning, pure-function

I have a function *num* with two variables, *matf* and *matg*. How can I combine the *last two* lines of code below into one? The code is aimed to find out the maxiaml count *bel* when we give each $i3 = 1,\cdots,5$ a value $f[[i3]]$ and each $i4 = 1,\cdots,5$ a value $g[[i4]]$. How can I speed up this code? Any help or suggestions will be appreciated.

```
 FG = Tuples[{0, 1, 2, 3}, 5];
 num[matf_, matg_] := 
   Module[{f = matf, g = matg}, 
     bel = 0;
     For[i3 = 1, i3 <= 5, i3++, 
       For[i4 = 1, i4 <= 5, i4++, 
         If[Mod[IntegerPart[(i3 + i4)/2 - 1], 5] == Mod[f[[i3]] + g[[i4]], 5], bel++];
       ];
     ];
     bel
   ];
num2[f_] := Max[num[f, #] & /@ FG]
Max[num2[#] & /@ FG]
```

Here is an example to explain what does *num* do.

```
Bell = {};
f = {0, 0, 1, 3, 4};
g = {1, 3, 2, 4, 1};
For[i3 = 1, i3 <= 5, i3++, 
  For[i4 = 1, i4 <= 5, i4++, 
   If[Mod[IntegerPart[(i3 + i4)/2 - 1], 5] == 
   Mod[f[[i3]] + g[[i4]], 5], 
  AppendTo[Bell, {f[[i3]], g[[i4]], i3, i4}]];];];
Bell
Bell // Length
```

The output is

```
  {{4, 3, 5, 2}, {4, 4, 5, 4}}
  2
```

which means that if we assign each $i3 = 1,\cdots,5$ the i3th element in *f={0, 0, 1, 3, 4}* and  $i4 = 1,\cdots,5$ the i4th element in *g={1, 3, 2, 4, 1}*, then there is only $i3=5$ (the correspondig value is 4) $i4=2$ (the correspondig value is 2) or $i3=5$ (the correspondig value is 4) $i4=4$ (the correspondig value is 4) satisfy the condition *Mod[IntegerPart[(i3 + i4)/2 - 1], 5] == Mod[f[[i3]] + g[[i4]], 5]*.

Comment: can you define `dim`?

Comment: could you clarify what the aim of your code is? It appears you wish to count the number of entries of 5-vector matching a constraint by position. There are 1024 tuples, are you wishing to oairwise apply counting function then determine maximum count?

Comment: Your code is very strange. You localize `matf` and `matg`, which are already localized, but you fail to localize `bel`, which would benefit from localization.

Comment: @PinguinDirk Thanks, I update the code.

Comment: @ubpdqn Thanks, yeap. I update the code.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks! I do not know about 'localize' and you can update the code to make it more brief or faster.

Comment: Thank you for editing the code. I am still a little confused as the SlotSequence is being applied to a list and consequently # yields the same result as #. I just wish to e clear what  your  aim is.

Comment: I am sorry Eden, is it possible to give a test example of num applied to two arguments to see what you intend. I am concerned that what you intend and what is coded do not match.

Comment: Your question title makes no sense to me... What two usages of `##` are you trying to combine? I don't even see a single usage

Comment: @rm-rf Thanks! I update the title.

Comment: @EdenHarder It still doesn't make sense, because your question is about the last two lines and not about `num`. Why do you need this complicated function? Why not replace it with a dummy function `f`?

Comment: @rm-rf Thanks! I update the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two questions embedded in the post, one about combining two lines, and another about efficiency.

#### Composition

The last two lines,

```
num2[f_] := Max[num[f, #] & /@ FG]
Max[num2[#] & /@ FG]
```

are the same as

```
Max[Function[f, Max[num[f, #] & /@ FG]] /@ FG]
```

They are also equivalent to

```
Max[Max /@ Outer[num, FG, FG, 1]]
```

or simply

```
Max[Outer[num, FG, FG, 1]]
```

#### Efficiency

Here's one improvement:

```
num3[f_, g_] := With[{gt = Transpose[g]}, 
  Length[f]^2 - Total @ Unitize[
     Mod[IntegerPart[(#1 + #2)/2 - 1] - (f[[#1]] + gt[[#2]]), 5] & @@ 
      Transpose @ Tuples[Range @ Length @ f, 2]]]

Max[num3[#, FG] & /@ FG] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.683202, 21} *)
```

Almost 200 times faster than the OP's functions.

Comment: Thanks so much! If we also use `ft`(use like `gt`) in the code, it will be much faster.